A bird that is about as UNBIRD-LIKE as it is possible for a bird to be. | Is "unbird-like" applicable to other nouns?

"In these forests lives a bird that is about as unbird-like as it is possible for a bird to be." BBC (See:0:00-0:08)

The word unbird-like caught my attention. Probably never seen such a usage. However, it is on the BBC, so I wonder if the usage unbird-like a common way of making new words? For instance, can I say to a student:

*You are a student that is about as unstudent-like as it is possible for a student to be."


I'd wouldn't hyphenate, "unbird-like"  I would write either "un-birdlike" or "unbirdlike"

English is flexible like that. And it won't be in the dictionaries. It's not common but it's doable.

What’s an “unbird”?

@user3840170 it's not "unbird",  it's "(un)birdlike" i.e. "unlike any bird"

I'd say that the context helps here too. The phrase immediately preceding "unbird-like" mentions there's a bird living in a forest.  While another word might be technically/grammatically "better", for parallelism, "unbird-like" works just fine here.

@Mari-LouA That would have been “un-birdlike”. But it’s clearly a comparison to an unbird, whatever that is.

@JamesK another option is "un-bird-like," though only to be recommended for those who would use "bird-like" instead of "birdlike."  For some reason, most people seem to avoid having multiple hyphens in such constructions, which often leads to ambiguity or, as in this case, absurdity.

There are some alternatives based on different grammatical forms:
He's as un-student-like as...: He's as un-studious as....

@user8356 That could arguably mean the exact opposite, since many students are in fact rather un-studious. In my experience, being studious is more un-student-like than being un-studious.

This certainly reminds me of a famous passage from The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy, perhaps more correct: “The ships hung in the sky in much the same way that bricks don't.”

I disagree with this answer a little in that you can basically say "un-[noun]-like" with pretty much anything and get away with it. The clunky, ungrammatical nature of the phrase is usually to give a comedic effect.
I found this Pintrest post of ridiculous chairs and one might say "That's the most un-chair-like chair I've ever seen".
To the extreme end, you might even hear someone say "you're the most unstudentest student to ever student". The phrase is technically nonsensical, especially with making "student" a verb at the end, but that's basically the point. Most native speakers will get the gist of what you're saying and they'll know you're playing with words, which conveys the lightheartedness.
I am not saying that this is common, but you might encounter such constructions when people are emphasising a humorous point. Essentially, just because it's ungrammatical doesn't mean you won't encounter it, and it's usually done deliberately.

+1. The chairs were a very good example of a context ripe for unchairlike.  But if comedic effect is not your intention, follow the advice offered in the answer by  JamesK.

I now wonder whether there is a term for this use of language. Basically, they're having fun with the language, mashing together or inventing words, and everyone else blatantly knows it, which is what makes it humorous to them, too

Most-unstudentist? Is that a typo for something like most unstudentlike? I don’t know what a studentist is (someone who studies studentism, whatever that is), and most doesn’t usually take a hyphen before attributive adjectives.

@JanusBahsJacquet no, it's a completely made up word. But its construction follows enough rules about actual superlatives that someone would "understand" it. I deliberately made the sentence ridiculous because, well, people do invent words when they're trying to be silly

I don’t think people would understand that one, primarily because *studentist isn’t a thing and doesn’t make enough sense to be understood as a neologism without explanation. It could be someone studying to become a dentist, or someone who adheres to studentism (which does seem to exist, but is extremely obscure).

It doesn't sit in isolation. It's immediately followed by the word "student", which gives it full context.

@JanusBahsJacquet I wonder how you'd handle I can't even. That's far worse than my "studentist" construction. The point is, people do actually break grammatical rules all the time and it's still understood

@JanusBahsJacquet now I'm wondering if you're suggesting a typo between "unstudentist" and "unstudentest". In which case, I'd agree on that one

Ah, if you meant it to be a superlative rather than adherent of an -ism, that would be a different matter. ‘The most unstudentest student to ever student’ would be perfectly understandable (though still without the hyphen). Didn’t think of that option at all.

@roganjosh That's why teenage girls always cluster in groups of three. They can't even.

@pipe huh, indeed, I've always found that fact odd

"birdlike" is a common enough compound to be recorded in dictionaries: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/birdlike
It is then regular to use "un-" to negate the adjective. The "un-" prefix is very productive.  The -like suffix is less productive.
Then, "student-like" is not a common adjective.  It exists in Wiktionary, but not in general dictionaries.
This means that, normally, you should avoid "studentlike" in favour of "like a student",  and likewise, you should avoid "un-studentlike"

+1, even though I actually think it's productive enough to use with arbitrary nouns. I wouldn't raise an eyebrow at "unstudentlike".

Another quite common example is unlady-like, see e.g. Google ngram or Merriam-webster.

ladylike fits the advice given by JamesK.  If the   adjective ending in -like has enjoyed widespread use (which "ladylike" did at one time) then it is a candidate for being negated with the un- prefix.

@Edheldil: Your ngram link is misleading. All hyphenated versions of unladylike have effectively zero currency by comparison with the unhyphenated version (which is the version in your dictionary link, obviously! :)

I am not a native speaker, but my feeling tells me that only adjectives can be negated, not nouns. So, if not for humorous effect, I would expect bird-unlike, what does a native speaker say to this alternative?

@rexkogitans That sounds highly ungrammatical to me. "un-birdlike" would be the way to do it; "birdlike" is an adjective.

@rexkogitans "Bird-unlike" definitely sounds wrong to me. We have the suffix "-like," but there's no such suffix as "-unlike," and the prefix "un-" can't be attached directly to the suffix "-like."

Since other people have mentioned that this usage is humorous and informal, I’ll give some alternatives for learners who want them.
In formal written English, someone who wanted to say a bird is nothing like other birds would likely use a word like unusual, atypical or anomalous, or a phrase like, “not like other birds” (positive connotation) or “barely a bird at all” (negative connotation).  Saying that something is a technically or formally a bird implies that it meets the definition but that this is not relevant or significant. Saying that something is supposedly or ostensibly a bird implies it is not really one.
Some real-world examples include, “sponges are considered animals” (implying that this is questionable) and “sponges are unusual animals.”

I agree entirely with this answer, but would just like to present a simpler explanation.
The antonym of "like" (meaning having the same characteristics or qualities as; similar to) is "unlike".
"Un-" is a recognised prefix meaning 'not' or 'the opposite of', and "-like" is a recognised suffix used to form adjectives that describe something as having the characteristics or qualities of whatever the base word is. So it is reasonable that any noun for which you can add the suffix "-like" can also take the prefix "un-" to form a new word.
There ought to be no need for hyphenation (your example was styled as "unbird-like"). Words like unladylike and unbusinesslike are not normally written that way. However, hyphenation can sometimes be added into a compound word for clarity if a writer thinks it may not be recognised. Hyphenation can help a reader see the component parts of the word. "Unbirdlike" may not be a commonly used word so I can understand why they might have hyphenated it, but personally I don't see the need.

The -like suffix turns the noun into an adjective, just as adding suffixes like ish or y does. Any particular  combination may or may not be idiomatic but should be understandable.
Prefixes un or in can be used to negate adjectives. Again, it may or may not be idiomatic, and the two may convey different connotations; unhuman and inhuman, for example.
So, yes, the formulation un-X-like is syntactically valid for most nouns, given the right formulation. But it may sound unnatural, and may not carry the connotations you intended.
